# Django jquery expander plugin not working with linebreaks

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm using django and the jquery expander plugin http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/. When I use the default example everything works properly. But when I try to use it with database data it doesn't work. Is it possible that the script is executed before the data is rendered? Any suggestion on getting this right?

## edit

ok I found the problem. The linebreakfilter generates more than one p tag and abunch of br tags.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div.expandable p').expander({
      slicePoint:       50,  // default is 100
      expandPrefix:     ' ', // default is '... '
      expandText:       'show more', // default is 'read more'
      userCollapseText: 'show less'  // default is 'read less'
   });
});
```

html working:

```
<div class="expandable">
<p>ljddf adfsdf esaf nmnj asdf adsfsdafsdf</p>
</div>
```

html working:

```
<div class="expandable">
<p>{{ object.description }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pointed out the problem. The linebreaksfilter adds some p and br tags to format the output. Instead of:

```
<p>some text...
some text...</p>
```

It creates something like this:

```
<p>some text...<br>
some text...</p>
<p>some text...<br>
some text...</p>
```

So the jquery expander plugin won't work correct with the output of djangos linebreaks filter.